# Image is not setting

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Here I am trying put image in view but I am not able to set Image in it I am using  third party library of setting circular view.I am getting error while setting image.

This code is in Main Activity and call when button is clicked.Any solution on code will be welcome

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case PICK_IMAGE_ID :

            Bitmap bitmap =ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this,resultCode,data);
            circleImageView.setImageResource(bitmap);
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is my Image Picker Activity which also contain trim of photo so that no heavy image get sent

```
    public class ImagePicker {

    private static final String TAG ="ImagePicker";
    private static final String TEMP_IMAGE_NAME = "tempImage";
    private static Bitmap bm;

    private static final int DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY = 400;
    public static int minWidthQuality = DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY;


    public static Intent getImagePicker(Context context){

        Intent chooserIntent = null;

        List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();


        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK , MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data",true);

        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));

        intentList = addIntentToList(context,intentList,pickIntent);
        intentList = addIntentToList(context,intentList,takePhotoIntent);


        if (intentList.size() > 0){

            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() -1),
                    context.getString(R.string.pick_image_intent_string_text));

            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                                    intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

        }
        return chooserIntent;
    }

    public static List<Intent> addIntentToList (Context context, List<Intent> list,Intent intent){

        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,0);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfos :resolveInfo){

            String packageName = resolveInfos.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent targetIntent = new Intent(intent);
            targetIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            list.add(targetIntent);
            Log.d(TAG, "addIntentToList: " +intent.getAction() + " package " + packageName);
        }

        return list;
    }


    public static Bitmap getImageFromResult (Context context,int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent){
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageFromResult: "+ resultCode);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        File imageFile = getTempFile(context);

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage;
            boolean isCamera = (imageReturnedIntent == null ||
                    imageReturnedIntent.getData() == null  ||
                    imageReturnedIntent.getData().toString().contains(imageFile.toString()));

            if (isCamera){
                selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            }else {
                selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "getImageFromResult: " + selectedImage);

            bm = getImageResized(context, selectedImage);
            int rotation = getRotation(context, selectedImage, isCamera);
            bm = rotate(bm, rotation);
        }
      return bm;
    }

    private static File getTempFile(Context context) {
        File imageFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), TEMP_IMAGE_NAME);
        imageFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        return imageFile;
    }

    private static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Context context,Uri theUri,int sampleSize){

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = null;

        try{
            assetFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(theUri,"r");
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),null,options);

        Log.d(TAG, options.inSampleSize + "decodeBitmap: " + actuallyUsableBitmap.getWidth()
                                                            + " " + actuallyUsableBitmap.getHeight());
        return actuallyUsableBitmap;

    }

    /**
     * Resize to avoid using too much memory loading big images (e.g.: 2560*1920)
     **/

    private static Bitmap getImageResized(Context context,Uri selectedImage){

        Bitmap bm = null;

        int [] sampleSizes =new int[]{5, 3, 2, 1};
        int i = 0;

        do {

            bm = decodeBitmap(context,selectedImage,sampleSizes[i]);
            Log.d(TAG, "getImageResized: " +bm.getWidth());
            i++;
        }while (bm.getWidth() < minWidthQuality && i < sampleSizes.length);
        return bm;
    }

    private static int getRotation(Context context, Uri imageUri, boolean isCamera){

        int rotation;


        if(isCamera){

            rotation = getRotationFromCamera(context,imageUri);
        }

        else {
            rotation = getRotationFromGallery(context,imageUri);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "getRotation: " + rotation);
        return rotation;
    }

    private static int getRotationFromCamera(Context context, Uri imageFile) {
        int rotate = 0;
        try {

            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageFile, null);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getPath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rotate;
    }

    public static int getRotationFromGallery(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
        int result = 0;
        String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, columns, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]);
                result = cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Do nothing
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }//End of try-catch block
        return result;
    }

    private static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bm, int rotation) {
        if (rotation != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            return bmOut;
        }
        return bm;
    }
}
```

This code work fine in  picking image but not setting image to image view and it work well for 5.0 but the App is crash on JELLY_BEAN.

I am using 3rd party library for circular image

Error Code for 6.0

```
04-15 10:18:47.114 3754-3754/com.example.this_pc.framelayout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.this_pc.framelayout, PID: 3754
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=234, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/34 }} to activity {com.example.this_pc.framelayout/com.example.this_pc.framelayout.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileDescriptor android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileDescriptor android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.this_pc.framelayout.ImagePicker.decodeBitmap(ImagePicker.java:130)
                                                                                   at com.example.this_pc.framelayout.ImagePicker.getImageResized(ImagePicker.java:151)
                                                                                   at com.example.this_pc.framelayout.ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(ImagePicker.java:103)
                                                                                   at com.example.this_pc.framelayout.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
04-15 10:18:49.745 3754-3754/com.example.this_pc.framelayout I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3754 SIG: 9


Error Code for 4.2 a.k.a JELLY_BEAN

    04-15 10:11:48.709 12956-12956/com.example.this_pc.framelayout 

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.example.this_pc.framelayout.ImagePicker.getTempFile(ImagePicker.java:112) at com.example.this_pc.framelayout.ImagePicker.getImagePicker(ImagePicker.java:48 ) 

at com.example.this_pc.framelayout.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37) 

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432) at 

android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338) at 

android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) at 

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at 

android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at 

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283) at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) at 

dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post error log

Comment: Are you sure you not getting any red line under `circleImageView.setImageResource(bitmap);` and you are getting error while running the code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setImageBitmap instead of setImageResource

setImageResource expects a resource as attribute, in this case, an integer id

```
imageView.setImageResource(int resId)
```

You are giving a bitmap as attribute, so use setImageBitmap

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `Bitmap` as the content of this `ImageView`.

So, try `setImageBitmap()` instead of `setImageResource()` as below :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case PICK_IMAGE_ID :

            Bitmap bitmap =ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this,resultCode,data);
            circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see previous answer after I submitted.